# JSON value of type NSMutableArray cannot be converted to NSString

Tags: react-native, react-native-calendars

### Description

I've just installed the module and implemented the sample example, in Android, it is working fine but I'm getting an issue on iOS. When I'm dismissing the error by clicking on Dismiss, it is working for me. I'm also attaching the sample code.
i think it is an internal issue.

### Expected Behavior

open calendar without getting this error.

error message:

```
JSON value '(
        {
        label = increment;
        name = increment;
    },
        {
        label = decrement;
        name = decrement;
    }
)' of type NSMutableArray cannot be converted to NSString

+[RCTConvert NSString:]
    RCTConvert.m:56
__49-[RCTComponentData createPropBlock:isShadowView:]_block_invoke.97
__49-[RCTComponentData createPropBlock:isShadowView:]_block_invoke_2.98
__49-[RCTComponentData propBlockForKey:isShadowView:]_block_invoke_2
RCTPerformBlockWithLogFunction
RCTPerformBlockWithLogPrefix
__49-[RCTComponentData propBlockForKey:isShadowView:]_block_invoke
__37-[RCTComponentData setProps:forView:]_block_invoke
__NSDICTIONARY_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__
-[__NSDictionaryM enumerateKeysAndObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:]
-[RCTComponentData setProps:forView:]
__50-[RCTUIManager createView:viewName:rootTag:props:]_block_invoke.405
__44-[RCTUIManager flushUIBlocksWithCompletion:]_block_invoke
__44-[RCTUIManager flushUIBlocksWithCompletion:]_block_invoke.461
__RCTExecuteOnMainQueue_block_invoke
_dispatch_call_block_and_release
_dispatch_client_callout
_dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF
__CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__
__CFRunLoopRun
CFRunLoopRunSpecific
GSEventRunModal
UIApplicationMain
main
start
0x0
```

### Environment

- `react-native-calendars`: "^1.264.0"
- `react-native`: "^0.58.5"
- `react`: "16.8.6"

### i think error is here in `accessibilityActions`:

path: ./node_modules/react-native-calendars/src/calendar/header/index.js.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {ActivityIndicator, Platform} from 'react-native';
import {View, Text, TouchableOpacity, Image} from 'react-native';
import XDate from 'xdate';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import styleConstructor from './style';
import {weekDayNames} from '../../dateutils';
import {CHANGE_MONTH_LEFT_ARROW, CHANGE_MONTH_RIGHT_ARROW} from '../../testIDs';


class CalendarHeader extends Component {
  static displayName = 'IGNORE';

  static propTypes = {
    theme: PropTypes.object,
    hideArrows: PropTypes.bool,
    month: PropTypes.instanceOf(XDate),
    addMonth: PropTypes.func,
    showIndicator: PropTypes.bool,
    firstDay: PropTypes.number,
    renderArrow: PropTypes.func,
    hideDayNames: PropTypes.bool,
    weekNumbers: PropTypes.bool,
    onPressArrowLeft: PropTypes.func,
    onPressArrowRight: PropTypes.func,
    disableArrowLeft: PropTypes.bool,
    disableArrowRight: PropTypes.bool,
    webAriaLevel: PropTypes.number
  };

  static defaultProps = {
    monthFormat: 'MMMM yyyy',
    webAriaLevel: 1
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.style = styleConstructor(props.theme);
    this.addMonth = this.addMonth.bind(this);
    this.substractMonth = this.substractMonth.bind(this);
    this.onPressLeft = this.onPressLeft.bind(this);
    this.onPressRight = this.onPressRight.bind(this);
  }

  addMonth() {
    this.props.addMonth(1);
  }

  substractMonth() {
    this.props.addMonth(-1);
  }

  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.month.toString('yyyy MM') !== this.props.month.toString('yyyy MM')) {
      return true;
    }
    if (nextProps.showIndicator !== this.props.showIndicator) {
      return true;
    }
    if (nextProps.hideDayNames !== this.props.hideDayNames) {
      return true;
    }
    if (nextProps.firstDay !== this.props.firstDay) {
      return true;
    }
    if (nextProps.weekNumbers !== this.props.weekNumbers) {
      return true;
    }
    if (nextProps.monthFormat !== this.props.monthFormat) {
      return true;
    }
    if (nextProps.renderArrow !== this.props.renderArrow) {
      return true;
    }
    if (nextProps.disableArrowLeft !== this.props.disableArrowLeft) {
      return true;
    }
    if (nextProps.disableArrowRight !== this.props.disableArrowRight) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  onPressLeft() {
    const {onPressArrowLeft} = this.props;
    if (typeof onPressArrowLeft === 'function') {
      return onPressArrowLeft(this.substractMonth, this.props.month);
    }
    return this.substractMonth();
  }

  onPressRight() {
    const {onPressArrowRight} = this.props;
    if (typeof onPressArrowRight === 'function') {
      return onPressArrowRight(this.addMonth, this.props.month);
    }
    return this.addMonth();
  }

  render() {
    let leftArrow = <View/>;
    let rightArrow = <View/>;
    let weekDaysNames = weekDayNames(this.props.firstDay);
    const {testID} = this.props;

    if (!this.props.hideArrows) {
      leftArrow = (
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={this.onPressLeft}
          disabled={this.props.disableArrowLeft}
          style={this.style.arrow}
          hitSlop={{left: 20, right: 20, top: 20, bottom: 20}}
          testID={testID ? `${CHANGE_MONTH_LEFT_ARROW}-${testID}`: CHANGE_MONTH_LEFT_ARROW}
        >
          {this.props.renderArrow
            ? this.props.renderArrow('left')
            : <Image
              source={require('../img/previous.png')}
              style={this.props.disableArrowLeft ? this.style.disabledArrowImage : this.style.arrowImage}
            />}
        </TouchableOpacity>
      );
      rightArrow = (
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={this.onPressRight}
          disabled={this.props.disableArrowRight}
          style={this.style.arrow}
          hitSlop={{left: 20, right: 20, top: 20, bottom: 20}}
          testID={testID ? `${CHANGE_MONTH_RIGHT_ARROW}-${testID}`: CHANGE_MONTH_RIGHT_ARROW}
        >
          {this.props.renderArrow
            ? this.props.renderArrow('right')
            : <Image
              source={require('../img/next.png')}
              style={this.props.disableArrowRight ? this.style.disabledArrowImage : this.style.arrowImage}
            />}
        </TouchableOpacity>
      );
    }

    let indicator;
    if (this.props.showIndicator) {
      indicator = <ActivityIndicator color={this.props.theme && this.props.theme.indicatorColor}/>;
    }

    const webProps = Platform.OS === 'web' ? {'aria-level': this.props.webAriaLevel} : {};

    return (
      <View
        style={this.props.style}
        accessible
        accessibilityRole={'adjustable'}
        accessibilityActions={[
          {name: 'increment', label: 'increment'},
          {name: 'decrement', label: 'decrement'}
        ]}
        onAccessibilityAction={this.onAccessibilityAction}
        accessibilityElementsHidden={this.props.accessibilityElementsHidden} // iOS
        importantForAccessibility={this.props.importantForAccessibility} // Android
      >
        <View style={this.style.header}>
          {leftArrow}
          <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
            <Text
              allowFontScaling={false}
              style={this.style.monthText}
              {...webProps}
            >
              {this.props.month.toString(this.props.monthFormat)}
            </Text>
            {indicator}
          </View>
          {rightArrow}
        </View>
        {!this.props.hideDayNames &&
          <View style={this.style.week}>
            {this.props.weekNumbers &&
              <Text allowFontScaling={false} style={this.style.dayHeader}></Text>
            }
            {weekDaysNames.map((day, idx) => (
              <Text
                allowFontScaling={false}
                key={idx}
                style={this.style.dayHeader}
                numberOfLines={1}
                accessibilityLabel={''}
                // accessible={false} // not working
                // importantForAccessibility='no'
              >
                {day}
              </Text>
            ))}
          </View>
        }
      </View>
    );
  }

  onAccessibilityAction = event => {
    switch (event.nativeEvent.actionName) {
    case 'decrement':
      this.onPressLeft();
      break;
    case 'increment':
      this.onPressRight();
      break;
    default:
      break;
    }
  }
}

export default CalendarHeader;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved by downgrading `react-native-calendar` to version ^1.260.0

just run `npm i react-native-calendars@1.260.0 --save`

then clean and rebuild your app.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I resolved it by setting the `message` property in the Alert dialog https://reactnative.dev/docs/alert.

It's not required on the docs but it seems to throw an error when you have an onPress action set.

If you don't want to set a `message` property just pass an empty string like the code below:

```
Alert.alert('Booking Success', '', [
  { text: 'Close' },
  { text: 'View Details', onPress: () => console.log('test') },
]);
```